# Kafka scheduler based on Kafka Streams and ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Hi I'm trying to implement a scheduler with kafka.
The requirement is quite simple but the implementation a little less.

I would like to add headers to the original message :

- a timestamp (when the message should be transferred)
- destination topic

The goal is to forward messages from ***input*** topic to ***output*** topic if **timestamp > now()**

My feeling was to use a ktable to get messages where **timestamp > now()**

But I'm wondering if this could work.
Here I have the feeling we should re generate this table every x seconds and remove messages that have already been processed.

If someone can point me to the right API to use or has any ideas on how to implement this, it will help me a lot !

Comment: I don't think Kafka is a good use-case for creating a distributed cron. Try Airflow instead, for example

Comment: Never mind. I did it with the help of https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/schedule-ktable-ttl/kstreams.html